# Fast voice command library on Android, open source, works offline

Tags: android, open-source, library, offline, voice-command

I want to add voice control to my Open Source Android app.

The vocabulary I need is not big, just 5 simple commands: "Show", "Again", "Hard", "Good", "Easy".

What library can I use for this?

Requirements:

- Fast recognition, less than half a second
- Must be Open source
- It must NOT rely on non-open libraries like Google Play Services or others
- Preferably not too big

Comment: Not that I have something in mind (I'm not an Android dev ;) – but: should it work offline, and *not* using the (proprietary) Google-Services (or any other cloudy stuff)? If that's the case, don't forget to update us with details once it's finished, as "Google listening" and "network required" are my main arguments against using such things :)

Comment: @Izzy: Updated. My app is heavily used in China where most phones don't have Google Play Services.

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas! That makes me even the more curious, as voice-control without *that* would be something I'm really interested in (upvoted, starred ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the only library I have heard of that might work is [Pocket Sphinx](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/pocketsphinx/)

I have only used the desktop version Sphinx but I believe it could do what you need.  You would have to create your own Grammar file but I would guess it would be pretty easy based on your short list of required words.

The license looks similar to the BSD license.

Comment: By about how much do you think my APK will grow after adding all necessary libraries and the recognition data for the 5 simple voice commands of the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) to create offline speech recognition.
But you can try this library for easy use without dealing with Pocketsphinx assets and configuration [RapidSphinx](https://github.com/icaksama/RapidSphinx). That's library can build dictionary and language model (Arpa File) on the fly.

Comment: By how much will my APK grow after adding all necessary libraries?

Comment: I'm glad can help you. The largest file from the library is dictionary file, it's about 3,2 Mb and the total of my library with codes is about 3.5 Mb. It's standard size from the Pocketsphinx.
And also only one audio record will be created from this library so if you try to record again, the old audio record will be replaced. So no worry. 
Please let I know if you need the new feature from this library with creating an issue in GitHub.